# Is this question about a man being harassed at work off topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, offtopic

This question was closed as off topic but it seems on topic to me. It asks for a specific goal in the subject. What do you think?
"As a male, how can protect myself from my female supervisor when she behaves inappropriately?" - [As a male, how can protect myself from my female supervisor when she behaves inappropriately?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/167794/as-a-male-how-can-protect-myself-from-my-female-supervisor-when-she-behaves-ina)

Comment: "What do you think?" is **not** a goal.  This reads a lot like a question that was geared for a hit as a HNQ.  If the community disagrees, they (you) can vote to re-open it.

Comment: @Neo I honestly don't see the problem with it but maybe that means many questions that aren't voted off topic are also off topic since I'm basing my opinion off my experiences on the main site to date.

Comment: There was an excellent edit made to the question, maybe it will be re-opened?

Comment: Most of the details in the question makes it more controversial and less applicable to others with a similar question and should be edited out of the post. The question probably wouldn't make all that much sense if one were to do that though, but then again the stated goal of the site is to create a library of questions and answers, which implies that such a question that's highly specific to one situation doesn't belong here. If anything, it would make more sense to create a canonical question from the opposite side: asking how to know whether you're being harassed (and how to deal with it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having read the original posting, I can understand why it was voted off-topic. "How can my female supervisor think she's done nothing wrong" reads sort of like a rant/complaint and by taking the question literally, one might assume the op is looking for a psychological analysis.

More than likely, the question he wanted answered is the newly edited version but I agree that it needed an edit to clarify that fact.

Comment: Ahh, when I first saw it that wasn't the question. I see...  Thanks.